# waitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x72c22ee000,peer=0x12d00280,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3

Tags: android, google-cloud-speech

Good day everyone, I would like to ask, hat is the cause of that ANR?. In my project I have service which is binded in a activity. Now when I exit in that activity the app is hang for a moment. My thought is that the service is still running though I unbind it in onStop() of the activity.

Here is my service class

```
public class SpeechService extends Service {

public interface Listener {

    /**
     * Called when a new piece of text was recognized by the Speech API.
     *
     * @param text    The text.
     * @param isFinal {@code true} when the API finished processing audio.
     */
    void onSpeechRecognized(String text, boolean isFinal);

}

private static final String TAG = "SpeechService";

private static final String PREFS = "SpeechService";
private static final String PREF_ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE = "access_token_value";
private static final String PREF_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME = "access_token_expiration_time";

/** We reuse an access token if its expiration time is longer than this. */
private static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TOLERANCE = 30 * 60 * 1000; // thirty minutes
/** We refresh the current access token before it expires. */
private static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_FETCH_MARGIN = 60 * 1000; // one minute

public static final List<String> SCOPE =
        Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform");
private static final String HOSTNAME = "speech.googleapis.com";
private static final int PORT = 443;

private final SpeechBinder mBinder = new SpeechBinder();
private final ArrayList<Listener> mListeners = new ArrayList<>();
private volatile AccessTokenTask mAccessTokenTask;
private SpeechGrpc.SpeechStub mApi;
private static Handler mHandler;

private final StreamObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse> mResponseObserver
        = new StreamObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(StreamingRecognizeResponse response) {
        String text = null;
        boolean isFinal = false;
        if (response.getResultsCount() > 0) {
            final StreamingRecognitionResult result = response.getResults(0);
            isFinal = result.getIsFinal();
            if (result.getAlternativesCount() > 0) {
                final SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternatives(0);
                text = alternative.getTranscript();
            }
        }
        if (text != null) {
            for (Listener listener : mListeners) {
                listener.onSpeechRecognized(text, isFinal);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error calling the API.", t);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        Log.i(TAG, "API completed.");
    }

};

private final StreamObserver<RecognizeResponse> mFileResponseObserver
        = new StreamObserver<RecognizeResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(RecognizeResponse response) {
        String text = null;
        if (response.getResultsCount() > 0) {
            final SpeechRecognitionResult result = response.getResults(0);
            if (result.getAlternativesCount() > 0) {
                final SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternatives(0);
                text = alternative.getTranscript();
            }
        }
        if (text != null) {
            for (Listener listener : mListeners) {
                listener.onSpeechRecognized(text, true);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error calling the API.", t);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        Log.i(TAG, "API completed.");
    }

};

private StreamObserver<StreamingRecognizeRequest> mRequestObserver;

public static SpeechService from(IBinder binder) {
    return ((SpeechBinder) binder).getService();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mHandler = new Handler();
    fetchAccessToken();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mFetchAccessTokenRunnable);
    mHandler = null;
    // Release the gRPC channel.
    if (mApi != null) {
        final ManagedChannel channel = (ManagedChannel) mApi.getChannel();
        if (channel != null && !channel.isShutdown()) {
            try {
                channel.shutdown().awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error shutting down the gRPC channel.", e);
            }
        }
        mApi = null;
    }
}

private void fetchAccessToken() {
    if (mAccessTokenTask != null) {
        return;
    }
    mAccessTokenTask = new AccessTokenTask();
    mAccessTokenTask.execute();
}

private String getDefaultLanguageCode() {
    final Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    final StringBuilder language = new StringBuilder(locale.getLanguage());
    final String country = locale.getCountry();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(country)) {
        language.append("-");
        language.append(country);
    }
    return language.toString();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

public void addListener(@NonNull Listener listener) {
    mListeners.add(listener);
}

public void removeListener(@NonNull Listener listener) {
    mListeners.remove(listener);
}

/**
 * Starts recognizing speech audio.
 *
 * @param sampleRate The sample rate of the audio.
 */
public void startRecognizing(int sampleRate) {
    if (mApi == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "API not ready. Ignoring the request.");
        return;
    }
    // Configure the API
    mRequestObserver = mApi.streamingRecognize(mResponseObserver);
    mRequestObserver.onNext(StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
            .setStreamingConfig(StreamingRecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                    .setConfig(RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                            .setLanguageCode(getDefaultLanguageCode())
                            .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
                            .setSampleRateHertz(sampleRate)
                            .build())
                    .setInterimResults(true)
                    .setSingleUtterance(true)
                    .build())
            .build());
}

/**
 * Recognizes the speech audio. This method should be called every time a chunk of byte buffer
 * is ready.
 *
 * @param data The audio data.
 * @param size The number of elements that are actually relevant in the {@code data}.
 */
public void recognize(byte[] data, int size) {
    if (mRequestObserver == null) {
        return;
    }
    // Call the streaming recognition API
    mRequestObserver.onNext(StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
            .setAudioContent(ByteString.copyFrom(data, 0, size))
            .build());
}

/**
 * Finishes recognizing speech audio.
 */
public void finishRecognizing() {
    if (mRequestObserver == null) {
        return;
    }
    mRequestObserver.onCompleted();
    mRequestObserver = null;
}

/**
 * Recognize all data from the specified {@link InputStream}.
 *
 * @param stream The audio data.
 */
public void recognizeInputStream(InputStream stream) {
    try {
        mApi.recognize(
                RecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setConfig(RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                                .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
                                .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                                .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                                .build())
                        .setAudio(RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
                                .setContent(ByteString.readFrom(stream))
                                .build())
                        .build(),
                mFileResponseObserver);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading the input", e);
    }
}

private class SpeechBinder extends Binder {

    SpeechService getService() {
        return SpeechService.this;
    }

}

private final Runnable mFetchAccessTokenRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        fetchAccessToken();
    }
};

private class AccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, AccessToken> {

    @Override
    protected AccessToken doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs =
                getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String tokenValue = prefs.getString(PREF_ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE, null);
        long expirationTime = prefs.getLong(PREF_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME, -1);

        // Check if the current token is still valid for a while
        if (tokenValue != null && expirationTime > 0) {
            if (expirationTime
                    > System.currentTimeMillis() + ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TOLERANCE) {
                return new AccessToken(tokenValue, new Date(expirationTime));
            }
        }

        // ***** WARNING *****
        // In this sample, we load the credential from a JSON file stored in a raw resource
        // folder of this client app. You should never do this in your app. Instead, store
        // the file in your server and obtain an access token from there.
        // *******************
        final InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credential);
        try {
            final GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream)
                    .createScoped(SCOPE);
            final AccessToken token = credentials.refreshAccessToken();
            prefs.edit()
                    .putString(PREF_ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE, token.getTokenValue())
                    .putLong(PREF_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME,
                            token.getExpirationTime().getTime())
                    .apply();
            return token;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to obtain access token.", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AccessToken accessToken) {
        mAccessTokenTask = null;
        final ManagedChannel channel = new OkHttpChannelProvider()
                .builderForAddress(HOSTNAME, PORT)
                .nameResolverFactory(new DnsNameResolverProvider())
                .intercept(new GoogleCredentialsInterceptor(new GoogleCredentials(accessToken)
                        .createScoped(SCOPE)))
                .build();
        mApi = SpeechGrpc.newStub(channel);

        // Schedule access token refresh before it expires
        if (mHandler != null) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mFetchAccessTokenRunnable,
                    Math.max(accessToken.getExpirationTime().getTime()
                            - System.currentTimeMillis()
                            - ACCESS_TOKEN_FETCH_MARGIN, ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TOLERANCE));
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Authenticates the gRPC channel using the specified {@link GoogleCredentials}.
 */
private static class GoogleCredentialsInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

    private final Credentials mCredentials;

    private Metadata mCached;

    private Map<String, List<String>> mLastMetadata;

    GoogleCredentialsInterceptor(Credentials credentials) {
        mCredentials = credentials;
    }

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(
            final MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method, CallOptions callOptions,
            final Channel next) {
        return new ClientInterceptors.CheckedForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT>(
                next.newCall(method, callOptions)) {
            @Override
            protected void checkedStart(Listener<RespT> responseListener, Metadata headers)
                    throws StatusException {
                Metadata cachedSaved;
                URI uri = serviceUri(next, method);
                synchronized (this) {
                    Map<String, List<String>> latestMetadata = getRequestMetadata(uri);
                    if (mLastMetadata == null || mLastMetadata != latestMetadata) {
                        mLastMetadata = latestMetadata;
                        mCached = toHeaders(mLastMetadata);
                    }
                    cachedSaved = mCached;
                }
                headers.merge(cachedSaved);
                delegate().start(responseListener, headers);
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Generate a JWT-specific service URI. The URI is simply an identifier with enough
     * information for a service to know that the JWT was intended for it. The URI will
     * commonly be verified with a simple string equality check.
     */
    private URI serviceUri(Channel channel, MethodDescriptor<?, ?> method)
            throws StatusException {
        String authority = channel.authority();
        if (authority == null) {
            throw Status.UNAUTHENTICATED
                    .withDescription("Channel has no authority")
                    .asException();
        }
        // Always use HTTPS, by definition.
        final String scheme = "https";
        final int defaultPort = 443;
        String path = "/" + MethodDescriptor.extractFullServiceName(method.getFullMethodName());
        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI(scheme, authority, path, null, null);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw Status.UNAUTHENTICATED
                    .withDescription("Unable to construct service URI for auth")
                    .withCause(e).asException();
        }
        // The default port must not be present. Alternative ports should be present.
        if (uri.getPort() == defaultPort) {
            uri = removePort(uri);
        }
        return uri;
    }

    private URI removePort(URI uri) throws StatusException {
        try {
            return new URI(uri.getScheme(), uri.getUserInfo(), uri.getHost(), -1 /* port */,
                    uri.getPath(), uri.getQuery(), uri.getFragment());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw Status.UNAUTHENTICATED
                    .withDescription("Unable to construct service URI after removing port")
                    .withCause(e).asException();
        }
    }

    private Map<String, List<String>> getRequestMetadata(URI uri) throws StatusException {
        try {
            return mCredentials.getRequestMetadata(uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withCause(e).asException();
        }
    }

    private static Metadata toHeaders(Map<String, List<String>> metadata) {
        Metadata headers = new Metadata();
        if (metadata != null) {
            for (String key : metadata.keySet()) {
                Metadata.Key<String> headerKey = Metadata.Key.of(
                        key, Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
                for (String value : metadata.get(key)) {
                    headers.put(headerKey, value);
                }
            }
        }
        return headers;
    }

}
```

}

and here is my activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MessageDialogFragment.Listener {

    private static final String FRAGMENT_MESSAGE_DIALOG = "message_dialog";

    private static final String STATE_RESULTS = "results";

    private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 1;

    private SpeechService mSpeechService;

    private VoiceRecorder mVoiceRecorder;
    private final VoiceRecorder.Callback mVoiceCallback = new VoiceRecorder.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onVoiceStart() {
            showStatus(true);
            if (mSpeechService != null) {
                mSpeechService.startRecognizing(mVoiceRecorder.getSampleRate());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onVoice(byte[] data, int size) {
            if (mSpeechService != null) {
                mSpeechService.recognize(data, size);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onVoiceEnd() {
            showStatus(false);
            if (mSpeechService != null) {
                mSpeechService.finishRecognizing();
            }
        }

    };

    // Resource caches
    private int mColorHearing;
    private int mColorNotHearing;

    // View references
    private TextView mStatus;
    private TextView mText, mResult;
    private Button editButton, clearButton;

    private SharedPreferences settings;

    private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder binder) {
            mSpeechService = SpeechService.from(binder);
            mSpeechService.addListener(mSpeechServiceListener);
            mStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            mSpeechService = null;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        final Resources resources = getResources();
        final Resources.Theme theme = getTheme();
        mColorHearing = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.status_hearing, theme);
        mColorNotHearing = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.status_not_hearing, theme);

        mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        mResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
        editButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        clearButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Sounds sounds = new Sounds(getApplicationContext());
                if(settings.getBoolean("muteAble", false ) == true){
                    sounds.playSound();
                }
                mResult.setText("");
            }
        });

        editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Sounds sounds = new Sounds(getApplicationContext());
                if(settings.getBoolean("muteAble", false ) == true){
                    sounds.playSound();
                }

                Intent editIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
                String forEditText = mResult.getText().toString();
                editIntent.putExtra("forEdit", forEditText);
                startActivity(editIntent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            this.finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Prepare Cloud Speech API
        bindService(new Intent(this, SpeechService.class), mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        // Start listening to voices
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startVoiceRecorder();
        } else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
            showPermissionMessageDialog();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                    REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Stop listening to voice
        stopVoiceRecorder();

        // Stop Cloud Speech API
        mSpeechService.removeListener(mSpeechServiceListener);
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
        mSpeechService = null;

        super.onStop();
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
            @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION) {
            if (permissions.length == 1 && grantResults.length == 1
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startVoiceRecorder();
            } else {
                showPermissionMessageDialog();
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }


    private void startVoiceRecorder() {
        if (mVoiceRecorder != null) {
            mVoiceRecorder.stop();
        }
        mVoiceRecorder = new VoiceRecorder(mVoiceCallback);
        mVoiceRecorder.start();
    }

    private void stopVoiceRecorder() {
        if (mVoiceRecorder != null) {
            mVoiceRecorder.stop();
            mVoiceRecorder = null;
        }
    }

    private void showPermissionMessageDialog() {
        MessageDialogFragment
                .newInstance(getString(R.string.permission_message))
                .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_MESSAGE_DIALOG);
    }

    private void showStatus(final boolean hearingVoice) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mStatus.setTextColor(hearingVoice ? mColorHearing : mColorNotHearing);
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void onMessageDialogDismissed() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);
    }

    private final SpeechService.Listener mSpeechServiceListener =
            new SpeechService.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onSpeechRecognized(final String text, final boolean isFinal) {
                    if (isFinal) {
                        mVoiceRecorder.dismiss();
                    }
                    if (mText != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (isFinal) {
                                    mText.setText(null);
                                    mResult.append(" "+text.toString());
                                } else {
                                    mText.setText(text);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };

}
```

Thank in advance for your help